# VBA: Get a data from another sheet while using a loop

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a hard time figuring what could have done wrong with my codes as it's not working at the moment. The thing is, I'm trying to get a value from another sheet and concatenate if from a data on the second sheet.

What I'm trying to say is like this:

```
Sub Test()
Dim config As Variant
Dim psize As String

'im trying to get the last row

With Sheets("Sheet2")
    LastRowC = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With


For Each MyCell In Range("D2:D" & LastRowC)
    'trying to get a data from another sheet (This is my problem so far as this code aint working.)
    psize = Sheets(1).Range("P" & MyCell.Row).Value
    config = Split(Range("C" & MyCell.Row), "-")
    'as you can see, im trying to echo out psize but to no avail
    MyCell.Value = config(0) & "-" & config(1) & "-" & psize

Next MyCell

End Sub
```

My Problem here is the psize variable as it doesnt get the value that I wanted in sheet 1. Hope you guys can help me. Thanks!

Comment: What specific error do you get? I tested it and seemed to work for me...

Comment: @AlexP No error, its just it doesnt echo out the value of psize. If I trying using a string into it, it echos out though, like for example psize = "Size 32"

Comment: you use sheet name and index mixed Sheets("Sheet2") vs Sheets(1), this can be the reason, note that excel may not index the sheets as one would think, try to use sheet names.

Answer (score 0):

You're not explicitly setting the context of the range object in this line. Is this referencing the range you're expecting? To make sure, try to use SHEET.RANGE instead here:

```
config = Split(Range("C" & MyCell.Row), "-")
```

Update - actually, also in this line too:

```
For Each MyCell In Range("D2:D" & LastRowC)
```